# Extract data from AWS Topic by Arduino code

Tags: amazon-web-services, arduino, arduino-esp8266

I am using MCU ESP8266 that is connected to AWS cloud.
I made a topic in AWS cloud called "**inTopic**" and its content:

{

"Parameter": "AAA"

"value": "1"

}

and I send it from AWS and Arduino received it successfully when using this code:

```
void callback(char* topic, byte* payload, unsigned int length) {
Serial.print("Message arrived [");
Serial.print(topic);
Serial.print("] ");
Serial.print("Here is Payload");
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {  
Serial.print((char)payload[i]);
    }
}
```

Here is the output:
**Message arrived [inTopic] Here is Payload{
"Parameter": "AAA"
"value": "1"
}**

I need to extract parameter AAA and its value separately in String and Integer variables.
Meaning I need to get AAA in **String** **x="AAA"**
&
1 in integer variable **int y=1**.

I need also to make the **topic** as **String** format to compare it to a variable(**String** **TopicName**).

I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Please edit your question to include reference to the specific AWS service you are using. For example, is it Amazon IoT, or perhaps Amazon SQS?

Comment: All your questions are not really related to AWS or Arduino, it is fundamental about C++ programming. For how to parse a json object, you could use an library like [ArduinoJson](https://arduinojson.org), there are plenty of examples available online or even in the ESP8266 examples that came with the library. Alternatively instead of sending payload as an json object, it might be simpler to just send as string as "AAA/1", it make the parse easier with the separator '/'.

Comment: To your another request, you don't need to use String in order to do comparison, C++ offers a list of functions for string comparison such as [strcmp](ahttps://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/), [strstr](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strstr/".